# Querying ASP.NET page in Python

Tags: python, asp.net, beautifulsoup, http-post, python-requests

I am new to web scraping and I have spent half a day trying to figure out how to simulate a ASP.NET query.

The starting link is: http://cookcountypropertyinfo.com/default.aspx 
I am trying to use requests to insert '235 W Van Buren St, Chicago' into the form *'Search By Property Address'.* After submitting the query manually, the link changes to:
http://cookcountypropertyinfo.com/pinresults.aspx. I am trying to create a list/dictionary of the all the results and links on the response page. This is the code that I have so far but it isn't sending a HTTP POST request.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

#test with 235 W Van Buren St
#using urllib
URL = 'http://cookcountypropertyinfo.com/default.aspx'
URL2 = 'http://cookcountypropertyinfo.com/pinresults.aspx'

#headers
HEADERS = {
    'User_Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8'
}

#start new session
session = requests.Session()
r = session.get(URL,headers=HEADERS)

#create soup object
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")

#ASP validation and session fields
view_state = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATE")[0]['value']
view_state_generator = soup.select("#__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR")[0]['value']
event_validation = soup.select("#__EVENTVALIDATION")[0]['value']

#create FORM_FIELDS
FORM_FIELDS = {
    '__EVENTTARGET': 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$btnAddress',
    '__EVENTARGUMENT':'',
    '__VIEWSTATE': view_state,
    '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR':view_state_generator,
    '__EVENTVALIDATION':event_validation,
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$pinBox1':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$pinBox2':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$pinBox3':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$pinBox4':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$pinBox5':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$houseNumber':'235',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$txtStreetName':"W Van Buren St",
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$txtUnit':'',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$txtCity':'Chicago',
    'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PINAddressSearch$txtZipCode':''
}

#POST form fields
r = session.post(URL,data=FORM_FIELDS,headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
records = soup.find_all('div',class_='linkaddressresult')
print(records)
```

Can anybody please help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: How do you know a POST request isn't being sent? Can you confirm each of the variables has the value you expect? After you've done `session.post()`, what is the value of `r`, and how is it different (if at all) from what you expect?